# How to performance profile an embedded JVM

Tags: java, c++, jvm

Our C++ software creates an embedded JVM, which does enough work that it would benefit from performance profiling.  However, I've never been able to profile the embedded JVM.  Attempts to attach a profiler to a running process from Netbeans fail completely.  I suspect it can be done through some combination of options at JVM starup, and perhaps some external toolset, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: 'some external toolset' request for off-site resource?

Comment: I'm merely speculating that people with more experience in this field might know of tools or approaches that are available to help profile an embedded JVM.  I plead ignorance.

Comment: I would try Java Mission Control for Java 8+. This doesn't require any command line options.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about Mission Control.  Turns out I don't need it, I just needed the JVM options:
 -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder 
as described in this blog http://hirt.se/blog/?p=364 then netbeans attaches and profiles just fine.